# Can we apply community detection algorithms for word vector space?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, text-mining, social-network-analysis

As I understand we can apply community detection algorithms such as Louvain to detect communities in a social network (i.e. involves people).

But I am quite interested in knowing if we can use the same community detection algorithms such as Louvain to identify communities in word vector space (e.g., word2vec), instead of clustering?

Comment: How are you defining the edges, by thresholding a distance? I suppose you could, as long as your embeddings are not too high dimensional; just try it.

Comment: @Emre is it essential to have edges in between nodes (i.e, my word2vec word vectors) to use community detection algorithms?

Comment: You can't have a network or graph without edges, but your algorithm might be defining them implicitly, like I suggested.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I never thought about it. Btw do you have any suggestions to implicitly define these threshold values?

Comment: No, but I'd take a step back to ask what your ultimate goal is and whether this is the best approach.

Comment: @Emre Thanks. I actually want to cluster my vectors. I am currently using k-means. But it does not seem to work well. That is why I am looking for other possibilities of clustering such as community detection algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

["Improving Community Detection in in Wikipedia Articles using Semantic Features"](http://snap.stanford.edu/class/cs224w-2016/projects/cs224w-2-final.pdf)
This paper talks about various methods of community detection and might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, connect the embeddings by their similarity. Then perform Louvain over the graph. Prune first to eliminate weak connections.